# Why need another user when install rvm under current user on Vagrant?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, rvm

Added a user named `deploy` in Vagrant. Then change to `deploy` user:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ su - deploy
deploy@vagrant:~$
```

Now install `rvm`:

```
deploy@vagrant:~$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
gpg: directory `/home/deploy/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/home/deploy/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/home/deploy/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/home/deploy/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/home/deploy/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: /home/deploy/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key D39DC0E3: public key "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
deploy@vagrant:~$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/home/vagrant/.rvm/rvm-exec-test.XXXXXX’: Permission denied
```

Why it said this directory:

```
/home/vagrant/... : Permission denied
```

I have read the install script:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer

But don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you still run it from `/home/vagrant/` so after you did

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ su - deploy
deploy@vagrant:~$
```

you need to do

```
deploy@vagrant:~$ cd
```

so it will go to the home folder of deploy user and will install there

Comment: I am sure now at `/home/deploy` directory: `$ pwd (returned /home/deploy)`. But when run `$ w` it returned only one user named `vagrant`. I think that's the problem.

Comment: And, login the server from another server with ssh, when run the command works well! `$ ssh deploy@[vagrant_ip]`. The vagrant didn't refresh current cache after added a new user?

Comment: hum this is strange . as soon as you create the user, it will become available. so even when logging with ssh with deploy user and getting into deploy home folder, you still get the issue about installation into `/home/vagrant`? it will be a bash issue then ? how did you create the user and can you verify the `.bashxxx` files for deploy user

Comment: This is very strange. When I ssh login from another host. Everything works well. Only the Vagrant host not good itself. I created the `deploy` user this way: `$ sudo adduser deploy; sudo gpasswd -a deploy sudo`.